# A .NET EF Repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I inherited a .NET CORE project and have come across a setup I don't fully understand.

There is a `DbContext` in the DAL with "Domiain" and "Entity" models e.g.

```
> DAL
  > Models
    > Domain
      Person.cs
      Car.cs
    > Entity
      PersonEntity.cs
      CarEntity.cs
  > Repositories
    > PersonRepository.cs
    > CarRepository.cs
```

And in each repository, the `DbContext` is accessed to get the `Person` model - which is immediately automapped like-for-like to the `Entity` model

I cannot find any differences between the Entity and the Domain models - so what is the point? What situation would demand this setup?

I understand `ViewModels` usage and abstracting to different models *in a business logic layer* but I can't think of an example where the repository commands would return or use a different model to the `Domain` models given here.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Questions of the ilk "what was developer X thinking when..." are hard enough to answer when it's talking about a design team whose members post here (eg "why did MS decide to implement X by doing Y..").. Some of your questions are perhaps impossible to answer. Post Person/PersonEntity and Car/CarEntity. Perhaps it's a naive separation of instances to prevent unintended side effects of tracked entities being passed around and manipulated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better look into Domain Driven Design (DDD). There are lots of references in understanding the concept and below are few.

References:

- [Design a DDD-oriented microservice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/ddd-oriented-microservice)
- [What is DDD - Eric Evans - DDD Europe 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMuiVlnGqjk)

Basically, **Domain** are the actors in your application. They can perform certain actions (method calls) such as a Person can drive a car, a car can change its parts, etc. While **Entity** is your model when interacting with the database. You can combine those in a single class and it all depends on your preferred design. The concepts are what's important.

It seems that in your case the two were separated since method calls are not relevant to Entity Framework (DbContext). You will get to understand the code more as you go through it.

P.S. I know this question will be closed soon but I prefer not to place this in the comments.

Comment: I know this question is not SO format but sometimes I just take a punt because I find it's much more responsive and useful than the sibling sites. I've heard of, and even tried to implement and understand DDD on my own terms but I'd never seen the domain/entity split like this - what you say makes absolute sense having methods in one area but I find the mapping absolutely pointless and would prefer to pass models to separated classes or even use partial classes just to split the file! I guess the previous guy had another preference.